# AngularJS ngRepeat - how to repeat values sequentially

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to do the following html structure using angularjs ngRepeat:

[image: ngRepeat question]

Yes, that is a table with two repeated values 1,1, 2, 2 ... ten times.

The code is like this:

```
<table>
<th>expected</th>
<th>accomplished</th>

</table>
```

My problem is, when I use ng-repeat, I shall use it in one of the th tag. And so, it will repeat the tag ten times. I'd like to repeat one of the expected and one of the accomplished tag, sequentially.

Any help?? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the controller:

```
var values = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    values.push({title: 'expected', num: i + 1});
    values.push({title: 'accomplished', num: i + 1});
}
$scope.values = values;
```

In the view:

```
<table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
     <th ng-repeat="v in values">{{ v.title }}</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   <td ng-repeat="v in values">{{ v.num }}</th>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `th` tag with ng-repeat and just check inside `$index` value (odd or not) and render `expected` or `accomplished` text.